# Get the name of a href-tag

Tags: java, hyperlink, pattern-matching, href

I have a link like this:

[image: href]

I want to get the name of it (current community) with java. I tried pattern/matcher but I cannot remember a token for this case.

My href's are in the string 'title_string'

```
Pattern p_title = Pattern.compile(">.<");
Matcher m_title = p_title.matcher(title_string);
while (m_title.find()) {
    String m_title_string = m_title.group().toString();
    System.out.println(m_title_string);
}
```

Maybe somebody has an idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Reimeus http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6999902, to be exact

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the HTML as text, not as an image. Also consider using an HTML parser.